# How to tell Entity Framework to search local SQL Server CE or remote SQL Server interchangeably?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Ok, this is the plan:

I am going to write a bunch of `*.sql` and execute on my SQL Server, creating all the tables, indexes, constraints etc. Then generate the entity models using Entity Framework.

Then I am going to write a sync utility (Microsoft Sync Framework) to sync the SQL Server with SQL Server CE on client side.

Since I cannot download the entire XXX GB of data from the SQL Server to SQL Server CE, I will download the most recent ones and tell the DAL (with Entity Framework) to automatically fetch local SQL Server CE cache first, then remote SQL Server.

Question:
Will my plan work? How to I change the database connection at runtime? There has got got be a bunch of `SqlConnection`, `SqlCeConnection`, `SqlClient` and `SqlCeClient` I have to fix. But how and where?

Appreciate your help.

**EDIT**: After trying out several other routes, it seems for what I plan to do, can be automated by the Local Database Cache template. It asks for the remote SQL server connection, creates the local SQL CE, sets up the database provisioning for Syncing, supply the options to generate Entities. And after that, I can just create the POCOs using the Entity Framework 4.1 DbContext.

Anyone else thinks this is how I should be heading? Nevertheless, I still cannot see how I can swap between the local and remote database qhen querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use multiple connection strings, you have to change modify the .SSDL along with connectionStrings.  You can find a full sample with demonstration on http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Multiple-database-support-with-Entity-Framework.aspx.
Disclaimer: Have not tested the sample.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check it out. But for now, I think the Local Database Cache way could be better. I will study that to see if the multiple DB connection is automatically handled there. Please also see my OP edit.